# Disable HTML error check in netbeans

Tags: netbeans-8

I am using **netbeans 8.0**. While working in html file it shows a error for some tags. Can anyone please help me to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

click on the light bulb on the hint and you should be taken to the configuration screen to do that.

OR

- In the Tasks tab, click the filter button in the left,
- Choose Edit

In the Task List Filter dialog:

- Click New
- Enter a value for Name (such as "No Script Messages"),
- Uncheck the Scripting Language Tasks option
- Click OK.

then 
close/open the Task window or Netbeans

Comment: This message is displayed when i hover on the warning. [ The "valign" attribute on the "td" element is obsolete. Use CSS instead ].

Comment: you can click on the light bulb on the hint, then disable that notification

Answer (score 0):

use vertical-align while using valign as following

```
<table border="1" style="height:400px;">
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:top;">Top Foo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:middle;">Middle Foo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:bottom;">Bottom Foo</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is not like an error. It is just like a warning icon.